# Slice list to ordered chunks

Tags: python, list, slice

I have dictionary like:

```
item_count_per_section = {1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 2}
```

And total count of items retrieved from this dictionary:

```
total_items = range(sum(item_count_per_section.values()))
```

Now I want to transform `total_items` by values of dictionary following way:

```
items_no_per_section = {1: [0,1,2], 2: [3,4,5,6,7], 3:[8,9], 4:[10,11] }
```

I.e. slice `total_items` sequencially to sublists which startrs from previous "iteration" index and finished with `value` from initial dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find `total_items` at all. You can straightaway use `itertools.count`, `itertools.islice` and dictionary comprehension, like this

```
from itertools import count, islice
item_count_per_section, counter = {1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 2}, count()
print {k:list(islice(counter, v)) for k, v in item_count_per_section.items()}
```

**Output**

```
{1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3: [8, 9], 4: [10, 11]}
```

Answer (score 2):

dict comprehension of [`itertools.islice`d](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) `iter` of `total_items`:

```
from itertools import islice
item_count_per_section = {1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 2}
total_items = range(sum(item_count_per_section.values()))

i = iter(total_items)
{key: list(islice(i, value)) for key, value in item_count_per_section.items()}
```

Outputs:

```
{1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3: [8, 9], 4: [10, 11]}
```

Note: this works for any `total_items`, not just `range(sum(values))`, assuming that was just your sample to keep the question generic. If you do just want the numbers, go with @thefourtheye's answer